# Does print statement will make performance issue for a website

Tags: python, django, web

We are using the `python/Django` for web development. While development phase wile coding i tends to put `print` statement a lot places to check the control flow of the code.
And same code with print statement is uploaded for server,
I know logging is a place to be more suitable but i find myself more comfortable with `print`.

I want to know how few lines of code will make site slow, *if it makes it slow*.
Lets say i have 100 line of code and upon that i added 5 `print` statements. another way of looking into it is to i wrote a 105 line of code. Then in that sense i should not make difference (i suppose).

Does this will make the website slow ?

Comment: What I do is have a variable called debug and every time I print say if debug: print x. Then when you are done you can just set debug false and not worry about it.

Comment: Advice: make yourself comfortable with logging and `assert` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since the arguments will need to be converted to strings before outputting and that can be a costly operation.

**However,** using `print` causes another issue. Some WSGI containers, notably mod_wsgi among them, do not like anything sent to stdout by default and so will raise an exception whenever that happens. You can fix this by printing to stderr instead, but the performance issue will remain.

Answer (score 0):

prints to the console are *always* slow...

```
def computationally_expensive_function(x):
    xl = reversed(range(x)[1:])
    y = x
    for z in xl:
        y = y * z
    return y

In [16]: %timeit computationally_expensive_function(5)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 us per loop

In [17]: %timeit print computationally_expensive_function(5)
<lots of prints>
100 loops, best of 3: 1.87 ms per loop
```

if I take factorials of 400, then the computation per iteration goes up to 147uS, and the prints go up to 3.5ms. That means, just printing the results causes it to take >100x as long in the small case, and >20x as long in the long case.

However... as with anything performance based, that doesn't really mean you have a problem. If it's in a tight loop - very bad. If it's in code that's called once every few minutes or so, that extra 1ms of overhead you won't even notice.